# Trigger updating clob error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Trying to create a trigger that will update a [clob](/questions/tagged/clob) field to `rtrim` hard returns the application is tossing in.
Cannot get to the application code, so I see no other way to make potentially needed changes to the data with a trigger.

The returns are not always added.

This code is throwing error ....

> Inconsistent data type expected got clob.

I thought declaring the field would avoid the issue... but no...

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AI_master_set
  AFTER INSERT ON base1
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    master_set CLOB;

BEGIN       
    UPDATE base1
      set master_set= rtrim(master_set,chr(00))
      WHERE master_set = :new.master_set;

 :new.master_set:= master_set;      

END;
```

Comment: Don't use `update`, just assign the value: `new.master_set := ...`. Also: `rtrim(master_set,chr(00))` is always going to be null as you don't initialize the local variable in the trigger. So your trigger (if it did work) would set the column in the table to `null` regardless of the value in the column. Plus you can't change the inserted row in an `after` trigger. You need a `before` trigger

Comment: got it... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the horse with no name, and on [Oracle (11g) compound trigger not updating CLOB data field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982744/oracle-11g-compound-trigger-not-updating-clob-data-field), this should simply work:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER AI_master_set
  before INSERT ON base1
  REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    tmp_master_set CLOB;
BEGIN       
    tmp_master_set := rtrim(:new.master_set,chr(00));
    :new.master_set:= tmp_master_set ;
END;
/
```

Hope it helps.